# Jeditable inserts 'Click to edit' after saving?

Tags: jquery, jeditable

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.post_title').editable('editposttitle.php', {
                cancel    : 'Cancel',
                        submit    : 'OK',
                indicator : 'Saving...',
            });
        });
```

When saving text the text'Click to edit' is inserted into my element? instead of the saved text?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, found where I was going wrong!

I didn't echo the new value in my php.

Comment: For clarification: Jeditable sets the contents of the jEditable element to whatever content your server returns. If your server returns no content then it sets the contents to "Click to edit"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $_REQUEST["value"]; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was not opening the file up locally as a file, but accessing it through a webserver.  Not sure why this was the case, but as soon as I put the example file on a webserver it started working.